# Create desired json array of data from generic list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, json.net

I have two `tables` in my database `Stores`  and `Products` with the following fields

**TBL_Store**

```
StoreID (Primary Key)
StoreName
```

**TBL_PRODUCT**

```
ProductID (Primary Key)
StoreID   (Foreign Key)
ProductName
INT_TYPE
```

I am using the following query to create `JSON` array

```
   var data = context.tbl_product.Where(x => x.INT_TYPE == 1).ToList();                    
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

It gives me all relational tables data with `Repeated Entries`. 
I want my json to be something like this

```
[{
"Store": {
    "storeid": "1",
    "storename": "Nike",
    "Products": [{
        "ProdID": "1",
        "prodName": "NikeShoes1"
    }, {
        "ProdID": "2",
        "prodName": "NikeShoes2"
    }, {
        "ProdID": "3",
        "prodName": "NikeShoes3"
    }]
},
"Store": {
    "storeid": "2",
    "storename": "Biba",
    "Products": [{
        "ProdID": "1",
        "prodName": "Biba1"
    }, {
        "ProdID": "2",
        "prodName": "Biba2"
    }, {
        "ProdID": "3",
        "prodName": "Biba3"
    }]
}
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `Store` navigation property in your tbl_product

Create helper classes:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Product
{ 
    [JsonProperty("prodName")]
    public string ProductName {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("ProdID")]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Store
{
     [JsonProperty("storeid")]
     public string StoreId { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("storename")]
     public string StoreName { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Products")]
     public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Get the data in the required format (Notice Include method that will disable lazy loading to the store objects):

```
var data = context.tbl_product.Where(x => x.INT_TYPE == 1).Include(x=>x.Store).ToList();

var stores = from d in data
             group d by new {d.StoreID, d.StoreName} into stores
             select new Store{
                StoreId = stores.Key.StoreID,
                StoreName = stores.Key.StoreName,
                Products = stores.Select(s=>new Product{ ProductId = s.ProductID, ProductName = s.ProductName }).ToList()
             };
```

Then you can use your serialization on stores object:

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stores , Formatting.Indented,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });
```